# How can I get my UIWebView to scroll after it loads a PDF

Tags: ios, uiwebview

So I've got a UIWebView that loads up a PDF from local filesystem and displays it. I want to cause the PDF to scroll down a bit once it loads without the user having to intervene. Right now, I can only get it to scroll if I wire it up to a button and make the user press it.

Here's what I've tried:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    // doesn't work
    [self.webScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 5000) animated:NO];
    // doesn't work
    [self buttonPressed];
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed{
    // works
    [self.webScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 5000) animated:NO];
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, **try to perform the action after one second and half or a couple of second**. To do this, use `dispatch_after` that return immediately so the `method - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView return`:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)),     dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.webScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 5000) animated:NO];
    });
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks Matteo!

FWIW I found that even using .05 second delay works!

Comment: I've been looking all over SO for a less hacky way, but it looks like we have to rely on time delays to force web views to fully load before doing anything.